# what is appvars.php?

Tags: php

I was writing some php code with a couple friends of mine a while back.  I decided to look at some of the code we had written and noticed that almost all the php documents had the line: `require_once('appvars.php');` at the top.  I know that this isn't a built in php file, but one that they had created.  I figure it is probably something that they had copied from a tutorial or beginners book so I assume it is a common practice of sorts.

in short: **what are the contents of appvars.php** and **what is its purpose?**

note: The server has been offline for several months now so I don't have access to it and thus can't look at the source its self

many thanks stackoverflow

Comment: There is no way we could know what are in the contents of that file. That's a file that was located on your server, probably as a global functions/variables file.

Comment: Google is your friend. Not a question for here. First result in  Google.

Comment: The file `appvars.php` isn't anything *standard* per-se.  From the name, I suspect it contains variables common to the application you're looking at.  Things like database username/password, local paths for files, etc.  Stuff that is not part of the software, and is likely to be different from installation to installation.

Comment: If you had used (and I guess you don't ...) a VCS, then checkout the code and look at it.

Comment: ok, thanks everyone!  I couldn't find much on google about it, all of them were just code spinets of which used the require_once statement at the top.  I couldn't gain any additional information from google other than what I already had in my code

Comment: Why don't you open appvars.php in your code editor and find out? lol

Comment: @Ozzy as explained in the OP, I don't have access to the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More than likley a file containing common variables used within the application.

Impossible to tell without seeing the code though, it could just print an ascii representation of a pink elephant at the top of every page for all we know.

Comment: ahah, thanks for the good laugh.  Yeah, that's what I was guessing, I was just checking if it was a common practice which would give me insight.  All the variables in the programs are declared inside the php file themselves so I wasn't sure if I was missing something.